# how to mathematically have array border without actually increasing the array size?

Tags: arrays, vector, chess

So I have a game board represented by a 1d array of 64 squares and I wish to know when a piece is trying to escape the borders.

So for example:
Assume a king in the game of chess is on the X:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 X 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

it is easy to calculate the attacked squares with a direction vector:

```
-9, -8, -7,
-1,      1,
 7,  8,  9

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 X 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

also if he is on the upper or lower edges of the board:
I just add an if that checks if the square + directionvector[i] > 63 or
square + directionvector[i] < 0

so:

```
0 0 0 1 X 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The problem then comes when it sits on the side edges:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 X
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

This is what will happen it will "jump" to the wrong place as you see above.

Do you know of any way of checking this?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning of your program, you can precompute the legal moves for every piece and every square and store them somewhere.

Assuming that your squares are numbered from 0 to 63, then `KING_MOVES[i]` will store the legal moves for a king on square `i` (where `i` ranges from 0 to 63). For example, `KING_MOVES[0] = { 1, 8, 9 }` and `KING_MOVES[31] = { 22, 23, 30, 38, 39 }`. Similarly, for a knight in the corner, `KNIGHT_MOVES[0] = { 10, 17 }`.

```
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55
 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63
```

The number of legal moves is different from every square (a king has 8 moves in the center, but only 3 in the corner). You can store the number of legal moves separately (such as `NUM_KING_MOVES[31] = 5`) or you can terminate each list with a special value like -1 or 64.

To precompute these lists, you can convert each 1-D number to a pair of (row, column) coordinates and generate moves naively, with boundary checks. For a king on square 31, you convert 31 to (row 3, column 7). When moving to the right, you end up on (row 3, column 8), which is illegal, so you discard this move. When moving to the top-left, you end up on (row 2, column 6), which is legal, so you convert that back to a 1-D representation: 2 * 8 + 6 = 22. You append this move to `KING_MOVES[31]` and so forth.

This gives you the best of both worlds: faster and shorter code for move generation with no wasted memory on every board due to padding. The downside is a few kilobytes of extra memory.

If you're going down this path, you could also take a look at [bitboards](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Bitboards) for even faster move generation.

Comment: i dont really undrestand what you mean, how do you generate moves in this manner? what does *KING_MOVES = { 1, 8, 9 }* mean in terms of a move

Comment: I have expanded the answer to show how precomputation works. I hope it's better now!

Comment: catalan francau thats fucin genius!!! thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could get the row number from the cell index as `i / 8` (floored), and use that to check if e.g. a step to the right or left passed to another row.

E.g. here, on a four-column board, stepping to the "right" from position 7, we go to position 8. The row numbers for these are `7 / 4 = 1` and `8 / 4 = 2`, so we changed to another row.

```
....
...7
8...
....
```

But that's harder to do for diagonal moves, because you expect them to change the row. In the end, this is pretty much just turning the board into a 2D array, and the step offsets into 2D values, where you can check for overflow in the obvious way.

IMO, in principle what you're asking is impossible for a 1D board. With the board defined as a 1D vector (and similarly, the offsets as 1D offsets), then there are no edges within the board, and nothing to escape. Instead of this:

```
.ab.
....
...c
d...
```

you really just have this:

```
.ab........cd...
```

And it's obvious that `c` and `d` are just as adjacent to each other as `a` and `b` are.

Comment: yeah probably you are right, but i thought of a way that might work - I place the piece in a new array with borders and make all the calculations there and after I finish I just transfer it back to the normal board :) thanks anyways for the answer I will sure try that!